# Laravel SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am facing an integrity constraints issue when adding a new row to a table has relation with another table (children and visits tables) every child has many visits.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`vaccine`.`visits`, CONSTRAINT `visits_ch_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ch_id`) REFERENCES `childern` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `visits` (`ch_id`, `ce_id`, `emp_id`, `next_visit`, `notes`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (202151-15, 1, 2, 2021-05-21, this is a test, 2021-05-17 07:30:48, 2021-05-17 07:30:48))

I am understanding the error message that should the value in the foreign key (ch_id) in the visits table should be found in the primary key  (id) in the children key.
The problem is the value already exists in the primary table  but I am getting the same error
Here is my code and screenshot for the database

```
$visit=new Visit();
    $visit->ch_id=$child_id;
    $visit->ce_id=1;
    $visit->emp_id=2;
    $visit->next_visit=$request->input('next_visit_date');
    $visit->notes=$request->input('visit_notes');
    $result=$visit->save();
```

I am testing on value 202151-15 and it already exists on the children table as following:

[image: I am testing the value in the last row]

Comment: Are you able to directly insert from phpMyAdmin or its just giving error from Laravel ?  if your foreign key is correctly defined, i can only think of $keyType = 'string' in model.

Comment: got the same error from phpmyadmin although the value is already exists i don't know why

Comment: Can you make sure there are no spaces and the value is trimed in children table as well as the visits table.

Comment: You can try creating the record with relationship. Eg: `Child::find('202151-15')->visits()->create(['ce_id' => 1, 'emp_id' => 2, 'next_visit' => $request->input('next_visit_date'), 'notes' => $request->input('visit_notes')]);`. But first you need to create relationships in corresponding models.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?